# Most Pythonic way to assign an attribute to a class instance from outside the class

Tags: python, oop, properties

What is the most Pythonic way of assigning a single attribute to a class instance from outside the class?

Say I have the simple class below, and that `attr2` is calculated through code external to the class.

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, attr1):
        self.attr1 = attr1
        self.attr2 = []
        return

foo_instance = Foo("some_value")
```

I was told that using setter/getter methods shown below is bad practice, so I can't just do:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, attr1):
        self.attr1 = attr1
        self.attr2 = []
        return

    def assign_attr2(self, attr2):
        self.attr2 = attr2

foo_instance = Foo("some_value")
.... # Imagine here a bunch of code (external to the class) which will give me a value for attr2 ....
foo_instance.assign_attr2(attr2)
```

which I think only leaves 2 options

1. Assign the attribute to the instance directly.

   ```
   foo_instance.attr2 = attr2
   ```
2. Use a property decorator.

   ```
   class Foo:
       def __init__(self, attr1):
           self.attr1 = attr1
           self.attr2 = []
           return

       @property
       def attr2(self):
           return self_.attr2

       @attr2.setter
       def attr2(self, attr2):
           self._attr2 = attr2

   foo_instance = Foo("some_value")
   .... # Imagine here a bunch of code (external to the class) which will give me a value for attr2 ....
   foo_instance.attr2 = attr2
   ```

The property option is obviously superior if I have checks/conditions I want to apply to the variable before storing it, but what if I just want to assign the value of attr2 to the attr2 attribute, which option is considered best practice?

Isn't it "bad" to modify an instance attribute from outside the class without any evidence within the class' code that this is done elsewhere in the code? Using `@property` or defining a `assign_attr2` method would signal to the reader that attr2 is manipulated outside of the class.

Comment: If you don't *need* a property, don't make it a property. The interface from outside (`foo_instance.attr2 = attr2`) doesn't change when you introduce a property, so you can defer that.

Comment: Thanks! Isn't it "bad" to modify an instance attribute from outside the class without any evidence within the class' code that this is done elsewhere in the code? Using `@property` or defining a `assign_attr2` method would signal to the reader that attr2 is manipulated outside of the class.

Comment: Any "public" (i.e. not prefixed with `_`) attribute should be assumed to be freely modifiable by collaborators.

Comment: Don't *create* new attributes if you can help it, but assigning to *documented* attributes is fine.

Comment: A setter is considered bad practice precisely *because* it's unnecessary boilerplate around assigning to the attribute directly.